# Using multiple tab fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

this is my first time using tabs in an app and I feel like this will be a simple fix but I can not find the correct solution. I have 5 tab fragments right now but when I run it all of them contain the same material. I think the problem is with this method:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new MiscFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(MiscFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

I have the fragment set to a `new MiscFragment();` (which eclipse automatically built with a dummyfragment when I created the project)

And I have:

```
public static class MiscFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public MiscFragment() {

    }
    View rootView;
    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.misc_fragment,
                container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.miscgridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MiscAdapter(getActivity()));
        return rootView;
    }


}

public static class OtherFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public OtherFragment(){

    }
    View rootView;
    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup contatiner,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sb_fragment,
                contatiner, false);
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sbgridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new OtherAdapter(getActivity()));
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

(The first method and both inner classes are in my MainActivity)and it looks like they both use the same `"section_number"` so both `GridView`s are referencing the same thing. Both my adapter classes for each fragment have a different number of items in the `GridView` but the second one looks and acts the same as the first. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but here it is:

The problem was with the `getItem` method. It works as follows:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
    Fragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
    Fragment fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();

    if(position == 0){
       return fragment1;
    }
    else if (position == 1){
       return fragment2;
    }
    else{
       return fragment3;
    }
}
```

Then each (Number)Fragment() relates to the inner Fragment classes

Answer (score 0):

You never read the `section_number` argument in the fragment.

```
int section = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense. So do I need to change my `getItem` method to include all fragments, or remove the one fragment in there so that I can use it for all of them. And from there use `int section` in each of my inner classes?